# sedona error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opengis/referencing/FactoryException

Tags: geospark

> /usr/share/spark-3.0/bin/pyspark --queue=szsc 
> --master=yarn 
> --packages org.apache.sedona:sedona-core-3.0_2.12:1.0.0-incubating,org.apache.sedona:sedona-sql-3.0_2.12:1.0.0-incubating,org.apache.sedona:sedona-viz-3.0_2.12:1.0.0-incubating,org.apache.sedona:sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12:1.0.0-incubating 
> --driver-memory 4g 
> --num-executors 100 
> --executor-memory 8g 
> --conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=5G  
> --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=5G

spark-sql:

```
sql5="""
        select 
            'aoi' as type,
            b.shipment_id,
            b.order_type,
            b.sub_order_type,
            b.buyer_geo_lat,
            b.buyer_geo_lng,
            a.aoi_id as region_id,
            100 as region_level 
        from tmp_aoi_polygon_tab a, tmp_buyer_pin_tab b
        where ST_Contains(a.aoi_polygon, b.point)
"""
```

df5=spark.sql(sql5)
df5.count()

error log:

```
21/05/25 23:31:20 INFO FileSourceScanExec: Planning scan with bin packing, max size: 134217728 bytes, open cost is considered as scanning 4194304 bytes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/spark-3.0/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 585, in count
    return int(self._jdf.count())
  File "/usr/share/spark-3.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/usr/share/spark-3.0/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/spark-3.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o92.count.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoun`enter code here`dError: org/opengis/referencing/FactoryException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.strategy.join.TraitJoinQueryExec.toSpatialRdd(TraitJoinQueryExec.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.strategy.join.TraitJoinQueryExec.toSpatialRdd$(TraitJoinQueryExec.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.strategy.join.RangeJoinExec.toSpatialRdd(RangeJoinExec.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.strategy.join.TraitJoinQueryExec.toSpatialRddPair(TraitJoinQueryExec.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.strategy.join.TraitJoinQueryExec.toSpatialRddPair$(TraitJoinQueryExec.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.strategy.join.RangeJoinExec.toSpatialRddPair(RangeJoinExec.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.strategy.join.TraitJoinQueryExec.doExecute(TraitJoinQueryExec.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.strategy.join.TraitJoinQueryExec.doExecute$(TraitJoinQueryExec.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.strategy.join.RangeJoinExec.doExecute(RangeJoinExec.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDD(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputRDDCodegen.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:453)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputRDDCodegen.inputRDDs$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:452)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:496)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:720)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedRDDBuilder.buildBuffers(InMemoryRelation.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedRDDBuilder.cachedColumnBuffers(InMemoryRelation.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryTableScanExec.filteredCachedBatches(InMemoryTableScanExec.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryTableScanExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(InMemoryTableScanExec.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryTableScanExec.inputRDD(InMemoryTableScanExec.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryTableScanExec.doExecute(InMemoryTableScanExec.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDD(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputRDDCodegen.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:453)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputRDDCodegen.inputRDDs$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:452)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:496)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.inputRDDs(HashAggregateExec.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:720)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.inputRDD(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.mapOutputStatisticsFuture$lzycompute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.mapOutputStatisticsFuture(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ShuffleQueryStageExec.$anonfun$doMaterialize$1(QueryStageExec.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ShuffleQueryStageExec.doMaterialize(QueryStageExec.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStageExec.$anonfun$materialize$1(QueryStageExec.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStageExec.materialize(QueryStageExec.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$getFinalPhysicalPlan$4(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$getFinalPhysicalPlan$4$adapted(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:173)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$getFinalPhysicalPlan$1(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.getFinalPhysicalPlan(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.executeCollect(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:255)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$count$1(Dataset.scala:2981)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$count$1$adapted(Dataset.scala:2980)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3618)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3616)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2980)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 87 more
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

The same thing happened to me about 2 days ago and I finally found the solution, try to use and import the library:
For Scala:

```
"org.datasyslab" % "geotools-wrapper" % "geotools-24.1"
"org.locationtech.jts" % "jts-core" % "1.17.0"

import org.datasyslab
```

And for pyspark you need to import `datasyslab geotools` (ST sql functions) and `jts`.

This happens because sedona no longer incorporates the dependencies for its sql functions, I hope it helps you.

Comment: Facing similar issue . Can you elaborate on the steps performed for pyspark . 
Im trying to use ST_Contains and have included apache-sedona-1.0.1-incubating-bin/geotools-wrapper-geotools-24.1-sources.jar,sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12-1.0.1-incubating.jar,jts-core-1.18.1.jar with --jars after downloading them ..
still facing the same error

Answer (score 1):

For the **Python** solution, I use `pyspark`, within a virtual env. I added missing jars, into the virtual env directory of Spark `$DIR_VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/jars`, as follows:

```
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/datasyslab/geotools-wrapper/1.1.0-25.2/geotools-wrapper-1.1.0-25.2.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/sedona/sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12/1.2.0-incubating/sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12-1.2.0-incubating.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/sedona/sedona-viz-3.0_2.12/1.2.0-incubating/sedona-viz-3.0_2.12-1.2.0-incubating.jar
```

Instead, you can download them manually, and locate in the aforementioned directory.

Afterwards, exit and start over the `pyspark` shell, no need to import anything else explicitly.

Partially based on https://sedona.apache.org/setup/databricks/.

---

## Actual Python environment:

```
anytree==2.8.0
apache-sedona==1.2.0
astroid==1.3.2
attrs==21.4.0
certifi==2021.10.8
click==8.1.2
click-plugins==1.1.1
cligj==0.7.2
cycler==0.11.0
Fiona==1.8.21
fonttools==4.32.0
geopandas==0.10.2
importlib-metadata==4.11.3
joblib==1.1.0
jts==0.0.3
kiwisolver==1.4.2
logilab-common==1.9.2
mapclassify==2.4.3
matplotlib==3.5.1
munch==2.5.0
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
networkx==2.8
numpy==1.22.3
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.4.2
Pillow==9.1.0
py2puml==0.5.4
py4j==0.10.9.3
pyarrow==7.0.0
pydoop==2.0.0
pylint==1.4.0
pypandoc==1.7.4
pyparsing==3.0.8
pyproj==3.3.0
pyspark==3.2.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.1
scikit-learn==1.0.2
scipy==1.8.0
Shapely==1.8.1.post1
six==1.16.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
typing-extensions==4.1.1
venv-pack==0.2.0
xlrd==2.0.1
zipp==3.7.0
```

Disclaimer: I don't have enough reputation to comment in answers.