# Colab + sedona: TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Tags: python, apache-spark

Using the guide here: https://sedona.apache.org/setup/install-python/

Trying to use Apache Sedona in python on google colab. However, following the guide results in a `TypeError`. Any ideas?

```py
!pip install apache-sedona[spark]

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from sedona.register import SedonaRegistrator
from sedona.utils import SedonaKryoRegistrator, KryoSerializer

spark = SparkSession. \
    builder. \
    appName('appName'). \
    config("spark.serializer", KryoSerializer.getName). \
    config("spark.kryo.registrator", SedonaKryoRegistrator.getName). \
    config('spark.jars.packages',
           'org.apache.sedona:sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12:1.2.0-incubating,'
           'org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:1.1.0-25.2'). \
    getOrCreate()

SedonaRegistrator.registerAll(spark)
```

Result:

```sh
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-73-3e0f20bf8072> in <module>()
     11     'org.apache.sedona:sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12:1.0.0-incubating,'
     12     'org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:geotools-24.0').getOrCreate()
---> 13 SedonaRegistrator.registerAll(spark)
     14 dfx = spark.sql("SELECT ST_PolygonFromText('-74.0428197,40.6867969,-74.0421975,40.6921336,-74.0508020,40.6912794,-74.0428197,40.6867969', ',') AS polygonshape")
     15 dfx

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sedona/register/geo_registrator.py in registerAll(cls, spark)
     41         spark.sql("SELECT 1 as geom").count()
     42         PackageImporter.import_jvm_lib(spark._jvm)
---> 43         cls.register(spark)
     44         return True
     45 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sedona/register/geo_registrator.py in register(cls, spark)
     46     @classmethod
     47     def register(cls, spark: SparkSession):
---> 48         return spark._jvm.SedonaSQLRegistrator.registerAll(spark._jsparkSession)
     49 
     50 

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to download missing jar connector files, choosing one of the methods from https://sedona.apache.org/setup/install-python/#prepare-python-adapter-jar

One simple option is to:

```sh
cd $SPARK_HOME/jars
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/datasyslab/geotools-wrapper/1.1.0-25.2/geotools-wrapper-1.1.0-25.2.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/sedona/sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12/1.2.0-incubating/sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12-1.2.0-incubating.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/sedona/sedona-viz-3.0_2.12/1.2.0-incubating/sedona-viz-3.0_2.12-1.2.0-incubating.jar
```

This question is closely related with [sedona error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opengis/referencing/FactoryException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67691439/sedona-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-opengis-referencing-factoryex/71940181#71940181)